# docker container is is automatically paused

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Hi all i have found a strange issue in my docker swarm standalone mode infrastucture: on one server and only one service is automatically paused after 5 second of starting . docker unpause also does not helps .

```
020450186dc1        myservice:latest      "/bin/sh -c '/app/os…"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes (Paused)                                           server-15.myservice_2
```

After some time this service is in pause mode again . I have no idea who can stop this service and where can i see some logging info about it . I know that the service can be killed but i have never heard about pause . The other instances of the same service are working stable.

**UPD:** 
I dont see any special information on this issue even in docker debug mode . I just see that somebody pauses my container:

```
Apr 29 11:50:01  dockerd[1069]: time="2019-04-29T11:50:01.539113504+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling GET /_ping"
Apr 29 11:50:01  dockerd[1069]: time="2019-04-29T11:50:01.539687070+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.38/containers/debee0c7acb9aa0db2021719ee6ee3d084b88e47d9f2250b1af920f5271bf353/pause"
Apr 29 11:50:01  dockerd[1069]: time="2019-04-29T11:50:01+02:00" level=debug msg="event published" ns=moby topic="/tasks/paused" type=containerd.events.TaskPaused
Apr 29 11:50:01  dockerd[1069]: time="2019-04-29T11:50:01.570125095+02:00" level=debug msg=event module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/paused
```

Comment: Provide some logs and further information would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using docker 18 and ubuntu 18? I'm having the same exact issue and it didn't happen in my environments that are older docker/ubuntu @Oleg

Comment: yes docker 18 and ubuntu 18

Comment: @Oleg I cannot get around this problem. I hope someone responds. I'm thinking of going back to ubuntu 16 to avoid this problem.

Comment: @MostafaZare what other information would you like provided?

Comment: Did you check `docker logs CONTAINER` or eventually healthcheck status should there be support for it `docker inspect --format='{{json .State.Health}}' CONTAINER`?